# PHP Array in pubnub

Tags: php, json, pubnub

In pubnub I have uploaded the data as `{"sensorval":{"zval":64}}` in jsonstring format.

While retreiving the message it retrieves as

```
Array([sensorval]=>Array([zval]=>62))
```

but i want only `zval` and `62` to be retrieved and store in variables. how to
do this?

I want to upload the variables `zval` and `62` into tables in local database.

Comment: In PubNub PHP, JSON Objects are deserialized as PHP Associative Arrays. So as the suggested answers below suggest, just access the value as you would any nested value in an associative array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$arr = array("sensorval" => array("zval" => 62));
list($key, $value) = array(key($arr["sensorval"]), current($arr["sensorval"]));
```

`key` fetch the key("zval") and `current` fetch the value of the current(first atm) element in "sensorval".

[EDIT]

```
$json = '{"sensorval":{"xval":2}}';
$arr = json_decode($json,true);
var_dump($arr);
// prints array(1) { ["sensorval"]=> array(1) { ["xval"]=> int(2) } }
$arr = json_decode($json,true);
print_r($arr);
//prints Array ( [sensorval] => Array ( [xval] => 2 ) )
```

Which is equal to the array in my example.

You tell me that you get the data like this:

```
$pubnub->subscribe('che', function ($envelope) {
    print_r($envelope['message']); 
    return true;
});
```

In order to run the code as suggested, you'll have to look it up like this:

```
$pubnub->subscribe('che', function ($envelope) {
    print_r($envelope['message']);
    list($key, $value) = array(
        key($envelope['message']["sensorval"]), 
        current($envelope['message']["sensorval"])
    ); 
    printf("Key: %s, Value: %s", $key, $value);
    return true;
});
```

Comment: The above code works for the format                                                           Array ( "sensorval" => Array ( "xval]"=> 2 ) ) ;                                                                  But my client retrives data in the following format:                                                             Array ( [sensorval] => Array ( [xval] => 2 ) ) ;

Comment: @kani What is the difference between the two formats?

Comment: Array ( "sensorval" => Array ( "xval]"=> 2 ) ) ; In this format I could perform array2json conversion using a function. It returns {"sensorval":{"xval":2}}      This is a json string. But with Array ( [sensorval] => Array ( [xval] => 2 ) ) format I cannot perform conversion to json. It returns errors.

Comment: Are you creating the array exactly the same as you write here? That's not valid code.. Please provide a `var_dump` of your array.

Comment: `$arr = Array([sensorval]=>Array([zval]=>62)) ;` this is not valid syntax. Why do you try to create it like this?

Comment: I created the array in energia code and sent from CC3200 board to Pubnub. The format while uploading was json format                 {"sensorval":{"xval":2}}.                                                                         But while subscribing to the channel and retreiving data using php the format was:  Array ( [sensorval] => Array ( [xval] => 2 ) ) . I dunno what format this is ?!

Comment: I think you are confused about how `var_dump` or `print_r` represent the array. The array you are lookin at is the same as the one I created above in my answer - only the representation may look different.

Comment: I did not create in the above mentioned format. The data while retreiving from pubnub channel was in the format Array ( [sensorval] => Array ( [xval] => 2 ) )

Comment: How do you check the format of the array you are retrieving?

Comment: The below subscribe function in php code retreives data from pubnub channel and prints the message :                                                                                                           $pubnub->subscribe('che', function ($envelope) {print_r($envelope['message']); return true;});                                                                echo 'message';

Comment: Have a look at my edited answer. As you'll see, `print_r` represents the array this way. Have you tried to run the code on `$envelope['message']`?

Comment: So the difference is in print_r and var_dump functions. isn't it ? ..........            Thank you so much . I tried to upvote your answer. But couldn't do because it requires a reputation of 15. I'll do as soon as I get 15.

Comment: Yes, it's just how the array is represented for output.